# Что есть присоединяемые свойства зависимости

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Привет всем. Подскажите пожалуйста, что является присоединяемым свойством зависимости. Смотрю видео курсы по WPF. Там один парнишка, создает присоединяемое свойство зависимости:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MonitorPasswordProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(...)
```

которое следит за изменением введенных данных в контрол PasswordBox, для создания placeholder'а( чтобы если нет данных в PasswordBox, то отображалось слово Password, а если есть, то символы *** ).
В разметке он обращается к этому свойству вот так:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <Setter Property="local:MonitorPasswordProperty.Value" Value="true"/>
</Style>
```

Но как PasswordBox добавляет это свойство к себе? Это внутри WPF происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Это `DependencyProperty`, которое объявлено вне того класса, к которому относится.

`DependencyProperty` ни за чем не следит. Это PasswordBox при вводе данных сообщает всем подписчикам о том, что значение было изменено. Механизм связывания (binding) устанавливает связь между значением контрола и значением, сохранённым в `DependencyProperty`.

Разумеется, код типа `PasswordBox` не изменяется, и да это происходит в потрохах WPF. Если у типа нет собственного свойства с таким именем он посмотрит в коллекции зарегистрированных свойств.

Никакой магии, разумеется нет. Аналогичный механизм ты можешь реализовать сам на основе какого-нибудь глобального `Dictionary`. Просто WPF предоставляет этот механизм из коробки. В очень неудобном и топорном виде, к сожалению.

Comment: А в чем заключается эти не удобства? 
В принципе, я понял, что в видео курсах хотели показать по поводу присоединяемых свойств. Парнишка сделал два присоединяемых свойства - MonitorPasswordProperty и HasTextProperty.
MonitorPasswordProperty при установке в true, подписывается на событие изменения свойства Text в PasswordBox. В обработчике события он проверяет есть ли в Text что-нибудь, если есть то устанавливает HasTextProperty в true, иначе в false.
Затем он где нужно привязывается к HasTextProperty и все!

Comment: Отсутствие проверки на наличие свойства в CompileTime. Отсутствие проверки типа привязываемого свойства. Громоздкое определение в коде. Неудобная интеграция с не GUI-кодом. Привязка к конкретному потоку (в нормальной ситуации потоку Dispatcher'а) и невозможность работать с ними из нескольких потоков.